# double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: linux

```
*** Error in `./samp03svr_az4': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x3119ba30 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x752fd)[0xf743c2fd]
/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xf762dacf]
/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x1b)[0xf762db1b]
./samp03svr_az4[0x807fef7]
./samp03svr_az4[0x808013d]
./samp03svr_az4[0x8074c3a]
./samp03svr_az4[0x80763fe]
/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x6b2c)[0xf76d7b2c]
/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xf74bf17e]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0806c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 134758078                          /root/az4/samp03svr_az4
0806c000-0806d000 rwxp 00024000 fd:01 134758078                          /root/az4/samp03svr_az4
0806d000-08095000 r-xp 00025000 fd:01 134758078                          /root/az4/samp03svr_az4
08095000-08097000 rwxp 0004d000 fd:01 134758078                          /root/az4/samp03svr_az4
08097000-08155000 r-xp 0004f000 fd:01 134758078                          /root/az4/samp03svr_az4
08155000-08156000 r-xp 0010d000 fd:01 134758078                          /root/az4/samp03svr_az4
08156000-08180000 r-xp 0010e000 fd:01 134758078                          /root/az4/samp03svr_az4
08180000-081a2000 rw-p 00138000 fd:01 134758078                          /root/az4/samp03svr_az4
081a2000-081cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
09139000-0913b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
0913b000-0913d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
0913d000-0913e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
0913e000-0913f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
0913f000-52da9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
d83f4000-d83f5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
d83f5000-d8bf5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
d93f6000-d93f7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
d93f7000-d9bf7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
d9bf7000-d9bf8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
d9bf8000-da3f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
da3f8000-da3f9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
da3f9000-dabf9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ddbff000-dde00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
dde00000-dded5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
dded5000-ddf00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
de100000-de200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
de300000-de500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
de500000-de700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
de700000-de900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
de900000-dea00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ded00000-def00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
def00000-df100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
df100000-df200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
dfb00000-dfd00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
dfd00000-dfe00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
dff00000-e0100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e0100000-e0200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e1300000-e1500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e1500000-e15cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e15cc000-e1600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e1600000-e1700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e1700000-e1900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e1900000-e1a00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2300000-e2500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2500000-e2700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2700000-e2900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2900000-e2b00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2b00000-e2b21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2b21000-e2c00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2d00000-e2f00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2f00000-e3100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3100000-e3300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3300000-e3500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3500000-e3521000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3521000-e3600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3700000-e3900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3900000-e3b00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3b00000-e3d00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3d00000-e3f00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3f00000-e3f21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3f21000-e4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4100000-e4300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4300000-e4500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4500000-e4700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4700000-e4900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4900000-e4b00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4b00000-e4d00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4d00000-e4f00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4f00000-e5100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5100000-e5200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5200000-e5221000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5221000-e5300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5300000-e5500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5500000-e5700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5700000-e5900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5900000-e5b00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5b00000-e5d00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5d00000-e5eff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5eff000-e5f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5f00000-e6100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6100000-e6300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6300000-e6500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6500000-e66ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e66ff000-e6700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6700000-e6900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6900000-e6921000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6921000-e6a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6b00000-e6d00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6d00000-e6f00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6f00000-e7100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e7100000-e7300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e7300000-e7500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e7500000-e7700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e7700000-e7900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e7900000-e7b00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e7b00000-e7d00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e7d00000-e7f00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e7f00000-e8100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8100000-e8300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8300000-e8400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e845a000-e85a0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8600000-e8800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8800000-e8a00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8a00000-e8c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8c00000-e8cff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8cff000-e8d00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8d00000-e8dfb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8dfb000-e8e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8e00000-e9000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e9000000-e9200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e9200000-e9400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e9400000-e9600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e9600000-e9800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e9800000-e9a00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e9a00000-e9c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e9c00000-e9e00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e9e00000-e9f00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea000000-ea200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea200000-ea400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea400000-ea600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea600000-ea800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea800000-ea900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea900000-ea921000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea921000-eaa00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eaa00000-eac00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eac00000-eae00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eae00000-eb000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb000000-eb021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb021000-eb100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb200000-eb400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb400000-eb600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb600000-eb800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb800000-eba00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eba00000-eba32000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eba32000-ebb00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ebbff000-ebc00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ebc00000-ec400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ec400000-ec428000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ec428000-ec500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ec577000-ec578000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ec578000-ecd78000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ece00000-ece2d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ece2d000-ecf00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ecf78000-ecf79000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ecf79000-ed779000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ed779000-ed77a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ed77a000-f3400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3400000-f3421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3421000-f3500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3500000-f3521000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3521000-f3600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3600000-f3621000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3621000-f3700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f37e6000-f37fb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 353946                             /usr/lib/libresolv-2.17.so
f37fb000-f37fc000 ---p 00015000 fd:01 353946                             /usr/lib/libresolv-2.17.so
f37fc000-f37fd000 r--p 00015000 fd:01 353946                             /usr/lib/libresolv-2.17.so
f37fd000-f37fe000 rw-p 00016000 fd:01 353946                             /usr/lib/libresolv-2.17.so
f37fe000-f3800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3800000-f3821000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3821000-f3900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3910000-f3915000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 353934                             /usr/lib/libnss_dns-2.17.so
f3915000-f3916000 r--p 00004000 fd:01 353934                             /usr/lib/libnss_dns-2.17.so
f3916000-f3917000 rw-p 00005000 fd:01 353934                             /usr/lib/libnss_dns-2.17.so
f3917000-f39e3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f39e3000-f39e4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f39e4000-f41e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f41e4000-f41e5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f41e5000-f49e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f49e5000-f49e6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f49e6000-f6224000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6224000-f6343000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 76667670                           /root/az4/plugins/pawnraknet.so
f6343000-f6348000 rw-p 0011e000 fd:01 76667670                           /root/az4/plugins/pawnraknet.so
f6348000-f634e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f634e000-f635a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 76663934                           /root/az4/plugins/sscanf.so
f635a000-f635b000 rw-p 0000c000 fd:01 76663934                           /root/az4/plugins/sscanf.so
f635b000-f63ff000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 76663932                           /root/az4/plugins/streamer.so
f63ff000-f6401000 rw-p 000a3000 fd:01 76663932                           /root/az4/plugins/streamer.so
f6401000-f6600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6600000-f6700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6708000-f670d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 76667618                           /root/az4/plugins/dc_cmd.so
f670d000-f670e000 r--p 00004000 fd:01 76667618                           /root/az4/plugins/dc_cmd.so
f670e000-f670f000 rw-p 00005000 fd:01 76667618                           /root/az4/plugins/dc_cmd.so
f670f000-f671a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 353936                             /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.17.so
f671a000-f671b000 r--p 0000a000 fd:01 353936                             /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.17.so
f671b000-f671c000 rw-p 0000b000 fd:01 353936                             /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.17.so
f671c000-f6722000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6722000-f6723000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6723000-f7122000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7122000-f7129000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 353948                             /usr/lib/librt-2.17.so
f7129000-f712a000 r--p 00006000 fd:01 353948                             /usr/lib/librt-2.17.so
f712a000-f712b000 rw-p 00007000 fd:01 353948                             /usr/lib/librt-2.17.so
f712f000-f7131000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7131000-f7335000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 76667616                           /root/az4/plugins/mysql_static.so
f7335000-f737f000 rw-p 00204000 fd:01 76667616                           /root/az4/plugins/mysql_static.so
f737f000-f7380000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7380000-f73c2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 76667617                           /root/az4/plugins/crashdetect.so
f73c2000-f73c3000 r--p 00041000 fd:01 76667617                           /root/az4/plugins/crashdetect.so
f73c3000-f73c4000 rw-p 00042000 fd:01 76667617                           /root/az4/plugins/crashdetect.so
f73c4000-f73c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f73c7000-f7580000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 518316                             /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so
f7580000-f7581000 ---p 001b9000 fd:01 518316                             /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so
f7581000-f7583000 r--p 001b9000 fd:01 518316                             /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so
f7583000-f7584000 rw-p 001bb000 fd:01 518316                             /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so
f7584000-f7587000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7587000-f75a0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 353976                             /usr/lib/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
f75a0000-f75a1000 r--p 00018000 fd:01 353976                             /usr/lib/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
f75a1000-f75a2000 rw-p 00019000 fd:01 353976                             /usr/lib/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
f75a2000-f75a3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f75a3000-f75e3000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 353926                             /usr/lib/libm-2.17.so
f75e3000-f75e4000 r--p 0003f000 fd:01 353926                             /usr/lib/libm-2.17.so
f75e4000-f75e5000 rw-p 00040000 fd:01 353926                             /usr/lib/libm-2.17.so
f75e5000-f76c4000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 353980                             /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
f76c4000-f76c5000 ---p 000df000 fd:01 353980                             /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
f76c5000-f76c9000 r--p 000df000 fd:01 353980                             /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
f76c9000-f76ca000 rw-p 000e3000 fd:01 353980                             /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
f76ca000-f76d1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f76d1000-f76e8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 353944                             /usr/lib/libpthread-2.17.so
f76e8000-f76e9000 r--p 00016000 fd:01 353944                             /usr/lib/libpthread-2.17.so
f76e9000-f76ea000 rw-p 00017000 fd:01 353944                             /usr/lib/libpthread-2.17.so
f76ea000-f76ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f76ec000-f76ef000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 353924                             /usr/lib/libdl-2.17.so
f76ef000-f76f0000 r--p 00002000 fd:01 353924                             /usr/lib/libdl-2.17.so
f76f0000-f76f1000 rw-p 00003000 fd:01 353924                             /usr/lib/libdl-2.17.so
f76f1000-f76f5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 76667619                           /root/az4/plugins/TOTP.so
f76f5000-f76f6000 rw-p 00003000 fd:01 76667619                           /root/az4/plugins/TOTP.so
f76f6000-f76f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f76f8000-f7719000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 5204                               /usr/lib/ld-2.17.so
f7719000-f771a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vdso]
f771a000-f771b000 r--p 00021000 fd:01 5204                               /usr/lib/ld-2.17.so
f771b000-f771c000 rw-p 00022000 fd:01 5204                               /usr/lib/ld-2.17.so
fff60000-fff81000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack]
```

Краш со временем работы игрового сервера.
Как найти причину или хотя бы куда капать?

Comment: а исходники этого чудесного сервиса есть? Без них будет немного сложновато.

Comment: Капать на головы авторам, можно серной кислотой.